# EBNF with comma repetition

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, bnf, ebnf

I find myself doing the following quite frequently as allowing one multiple entries separated by a comma:

```
( function | expression ) ( ',' ( function | expression ))*
```

Is there a more compact way to do this? Ideally I'd just like to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
( function | expression ) [,...]
```

Or:

```
( function | expression ',')*
```

By the way, I am using this as a validator: https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui#_Production

---

The whole grammar I am trying to 'clean up' is the following:

```
AGGREGATION
  ::= 'GROUP BY' ( GROUPING_ROWS | PIVOT )?

PIVOT
  ::= 'PIVOT(' AXIS_EXPR (AXIS_EXPR ',' )? ')'

AXIS_EXPR
  ::= expr ( 'AS'? alias )? 'ON' ( 'ROWS' | 'COLS' ) ( 'HAVING' expr )? ( 'ORDER BY' expr ( 'ASC' | 'DESC' )? )? ( 'LIMIT' num 'PERCENT'? )?

GROUPING_ROWS
  ::= 'GROUPING_ROWS(' GROUPING_EXPR (GROUPING_EXPR ',' )? ')'

GROUPING_EXPR
  ::= NAME_OR_POS 'SUBTOTAL' 'S'? GROUPING_EXPR_SUBTOTAL (',' GROUPING_EXPR_SUBTOTAL)*

GROUPING_EXPR_SUBTOTAL
  ::= NAME_OR_POS ':'  AGGREGATED_CALCULATION ( ',' AGGREGATED_CALCULATION )*

NAME_OR_POS
  ::= ( name | pos )

AGGREGATED_CALCULATION
  ::= ( aggregation_function | aggregation_expression ) ( 'AS'? alias)?
```

And as an example of the construct I find myself using all the time:

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that using macros. Several parser generators offer this feature, e.g. parboiled2. You could apply the infamous C preprocessor or `m4` to do what you want. But, I don't recommend it. You don't save that much in engineering costs, which I suppose is less typing. However, the main reason I disagree with the feature is that it makes it harder for a tool to refactor the grammar, e.g., converting the grammar from generator to another, or optimizing it for speed or space in an implementation. Grammars should be treated as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ( function | expression ) ( ',' ( function | expression ))*
> ```
>
> Is there a more compact way to do this?

Other than introducing "helper rules" like this:

```
rule
 : atom_list
 ;

atom_list
 : atom (',' atom)*
 ;

atom
 : function
 | expression
 ;
```

the answer is: no, there is no shorter way to write `a (',' a)*` into something like `(a ',')*` with ANTLR.

If you're repeating `function | expression` a lot, at the very least make a separate rule of those alternatives.